# How to new insert tableview row in swift?

Tags: swift, tableview

I am working on two view controllers. In first VC there is a button when clicked it navigates to other vc and takes some values from textfields in an array and print those values in the previous vc's tableview row.
Now, I can add values to the tableview row once but when I try to add new values in that tableview it adds the values in the same row but what I want is that when I add new values it shows them on the new row. In short, I want to add a new row when I add new values.

I am adding values in an array:

```
arrObj.insert(KeyValues(date: textfield.text!, category: textfield.text!, amount: textfield.text!, tax: textfield.text!), at: 0)
```

And showing them in tableview cell like:

```
cell.label.text = arrObj[indexPath.row].category
```

What else should I add to insert a new row and show data on it. Hope I am clear with my question. Please ask questions if the question is not clear. Thanks!

Comment: It seems correct. But how do you reload the UI (ie the "tableView")? `tableView.reloadData()`? `tableView.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)]with: .top)`?

Comment: @Larme I used tableView.insertRows(at:[IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)]with: .top) but it crashs the app.

Comment: It crashes? What's the error message then?

Comment: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Your `tableView` is nil? How so? Could You have an important issue then.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like `tableView.reloadData()` after updating your array?

Comment: It gives this error everytime :Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That means this has to be initialized before assigning value to this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would try the following:

```
1 let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: arrayOfValues.count, section: 0) 
2 arrayOfValues.append(newValue)
3 tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Comments:

- In the first line, you calculate a new indexPath for your new cell.
  For that, you have to provide a row and a section.

How to calculate the row?

You use the number of elements in your 'old' array which will be now the index for your new value in the array (that is why you calculate the indexPath **first** and only **then** add a new value actually to your array)

- In the second line, you are adding your new value to an array (as it was described above)
- Finally, now you command your TableView to actually insert it so that it can be seen.

Hope it helps. If not, I will be glad to help you.

Comment: I get this error message on 3rd line: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: To give the most precise answer, I need to understand how you navigate back... What segue and method are you using?

To avoid that error, you have to safely unwrap the newValue the ViewController passed..! but to actually understand that, I need to understand what segue and how you are going back with that new value...

Comment: let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "viewcontroller") as! viewcontroller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
I am navigating back like this

Answer (score 0):

First You need to update You'r data and then, in `DispatchQueue.main` You nee to call `tableView.reloadData()` method.

It is the simplest way...